# Creating an empty table based on another table's schema in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

We have a BigQuery dataset that has some long list of tables (with data) in it. Since I am taking over a data pipeline, which I want to familiarize myself with by doing tests, I want to duplicate those dataset/tables without copying-truncating the tables. Essentially, I want to re-create those tables in a test dataset using their schema. How can this be done in `bq` client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options considering you don't want to copy the data but the schema:

1.- extract the schema for each table and then create new ones just empty.

```
$ bq show --schema --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] > [SCHEMA_FILE]

$ bq mk --table [PROJECT_ID]:[NEW_DATASET].[TABLE] [SCHEMA_FILE]
```

2.- run a query with LIMIT 0 and setting a destination table.

```
bq query "SELECT * FROM [DATASET].[TABLE] LIMIT 0" --destination_table [NEW_DATASET].[TABLE]
```